# Errors in python buffer when type docstrings

Tags: python, company-mode, jedi

When I type any text in docstring I've got an exception right at cursor place. May be it's some `python-mode.el` addon, I don't know. How should I fix it?
[image]

I use `company-jedi` and `python-mode.el`.

Comment: Please file a bug-report at https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues giving some plain code triggering the bug.

Comment: OK. But what is this? If this is some completion, how can I turn it off?

Comment: Does it happen when you start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`)?  If not, recursively bisect your init file until you isolate the code that causes the problem.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem and for me the problem was caused by `python-mode`. Removing `python-mode` and falling back on the emacs-25 default (`python.el`) solved the problem.

Comment: I don't use `jedi-mode`, only `company-jedi` and `jedi-core` (as dependency of `company-jedi`)

Comment: I deleted `python-mode` and now I have no problems =)

Comment: @CryptoManiac I was about to come on here and say the same thing! After I commented here I realised that the problem was still there. I deleted python-mode and now it works fine again.

Comment: I'm don't understand you) You don't use `python-mode` now?

Comment: that's correct. I deleted python-mode